# Getting the pixels matrix from mlx90640

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, decoding

I have bought an infrared imaging module(mlx90640), I want to get the pixels matrix from it using raspberry-pi 4.The module sends the data through a USB port. A lot of web links and libraries are dealing with mlx90460 module but most of them use I2C protocol. My module does not deal with this kind of protocol.

I have tried to read the input from serial port, then I got bytes like this:
b'\x06\t\xfb\t\xf6\n'
b'\n'
b'\t\xf6\t\xef\t\xfd\n'
b'2\n'
b'Z\n'
b'c\n'
b'\x97\n'
b'\x9a\n'
b'\xbd\n'
can anyone help me please?

Comment: can the uart to i2c converter be a solution?

Comment: You'll need to get a link to the documentation for the actual product you have. The vendor should supply that.